# How to push data from DB2 to elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, db2

I'm having dummy data in elasticsearch. Now I want push data from DB2 to elasticsearch using .net. how can i implement this

Answer (score 0):

Check Logstash, which able to send data to your Elasticsearch node.

I think you have to implement this in .NET. You can use Logstash API, or you can start Logstash by command.